# Can I use the same Redis instance for task queue and cache?

Tags: caching, redis

I've read responses to a couple similar questions on stackoverflow, and although it seems like sharing a single instance for two purposes is fine, I would like to know the potential downside.

My main concern is the cache filling up the memory and slowing down or breaking the task queue. Is this possible? I use caching heavily, so should I be worried about this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, you can use the same Redis instance for task queue and caching.

There're some downsides

- Longer query time
- High memory usage
- High CPU usage
- Backup

Any fail-safe task queue, makes a lot of Redis calls to move a task from one data structure to another and for other actions. You should check your task queue, and how many Redis calls it would make in seconds for 1 queues and N queues. If the number of Redis queries is proportional to the number of queues then you should check, can your Redis server handles such a large number of requests.

Since you're using the same Redis instance for task queue and cache, the number of entries in your cache could be very large, see it's not going beyond its memory limit. Losing cache data is fine but you should not lose task queue data.

Due to a large number of queries the CPU utilization would increase, hopefully, it won't reach 90% or so, watch for any CPU spike.

Given you're going to use the same Redis server for the task queue, you should enable backup for the Redis server, so that you can restore tasks from the backup. When you're doing a backup likely backup would be done for the whole data not only task queues.